# Mocking of Singleton Public/Void method failing with PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, powermockito

So here is the Scenario :

```
public class classA implements classRandom {
   public void methodA(arg1, arg2) {
       POJOb objB;
       objB = SingletonClass_Instance().singletonMethodA(arg1);
   }
   public SingletonClass SingletonClass_Instance() {
       return SingletonClass.getInstance();
   }
}

public class SingletonClass {
    public objB singletonMethodA(final String arg1) {
        return randomObj;
    }
}
```

I am writing a unit test for methodA in Class A. For this i have written the following stub code:

```
SingletonClass mockSingletonClass = PowerMockito.mock(SingletonClass.class);
POJOb = PowerMockito.mock(POJOb.class);
Mockito.when(mockSingletonClass.singletonMethodA(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(POJOb);
```

Now immediately after this code, i have a code:

```
POJOb objB = classA_Object.methodA(arg1, arg2);
```

This code fails as soon as it reaches:

```
**methodA -->  SingletonClass_Instance().singletonMethodA**
```

I have already used the following Powermockito procedures:

```
1) import PM libs
2) Added @PrepareForTest({SingletonClass.class, POJOb.class})
```

Still i am unable to mock the Public/Void methods of SingletonClass. They are always coming out to be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do something like this.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(SingletonClass.class);
SingletonClass mockSingleton = PowerMockito.mock(SingletonClass.class);
PowerMockito.when(SingletonClass.getInstance()).thenReturn(mockSingleton);
```

Comment: The getInstance() Is a static method, and just calling Mock(Class) the mockObject won't have mocked the static methods.  So you have to Mock the static class(which is why you are using PowerMocktio) and have the .when(Object.class.staticMethod()).thenReturn(whatever you want that static method to return).

Comment: which in this case is the instance of a mock object.